# Longest path for each node to a leaf in a BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

For each node in a BST, what is the length of the longest path from the node to a leaf? (worst case)
I think in the worst case we have a linear path from a node to a leaf. If there are n nodes in a tree, then the running time is O(n*n). Is this right?

Comment: First, in a tree, there's only one path from anywhere to anywhere, so theres not really a "longest" path, there's just "the" path. At worst, this is linear; if it's a balanced BST, then it's log)n). I'm not sure what you mean by "running time" - running time to do what?

Comment: I mean running time of the code implementation to find the longest path for each node in a tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in linear time, assuming it's "A given node to every leaf" or "Every node to a given leaf." If it's "Every Node to Every Leaf", that's a bit harder.

To do this: Walk from the "target" to the root, marking each node by distance; colors all of these nodes red. (So, the root holds the depth of the target, and the target holds 0). For each red node, walk its non-red children, adding 1 as you descend, starting from the value of the red node.

It's not O(n*n) because you're able to re-use a lot of your work; you don't find one path, then start completely over to find the next.

Comment: I see your point. However, if we don't use the optimization, then would not that be O(n*n)?

Comment: Yes, (unless the tree is balanced.) If the tree is balanced, then paths can't be more than O(log n), so the un-optimized version would be O(n log n)

Answer (score 0):

The longest path from a node to a leaf would be 
1. Going all the way from the node to the root
2.Then going from the root down to the deepest leaf
3.Things to ensure would be not to traverse a node twice because if thus was allowed, the path could be made infinitely long by going between any two nodes multiple times

```
    x
   / \
  b   a
       \
        c
         \
          d
```

The longest path from c to leaf would do two things

1. Go from c to x (count this length)

2. Go from x to deepest leaf which does not have c in its path (in this case that leaf is b)

The code below has a time complexity of O(n) for finding longest distance from a single node
Therefore for finding distance for all nodes would be O(n^2)

```
public int longestPath(Node n, Node root) {
    int path = 0;
    Node x = n;
    while (x.parent != null) {
        x = x.parent;
        path++;
    }
    int height = maxHeight(root, n);
    return path + height;
}

private int maxHeight(Node x, Node exclude) {
    if (x == exclude)
        return -1;
    if (x == null)
        return -1;
    if (x.left == null && x.right == null)
        return 0;
    int l = maxHeight(x.left, exclude);
    int r = maxHeight(x.right, exclude);
    return l > r ? l + 1 : r + 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually, exclude should be a list of nodes which were found on the path from c to x (and not just c)... I'll fix the code in the evening

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be.

1) Check if the node has subtree, if yes then find the height of that subtree.

2) Find the height of rest of the tree, as mentioned by @abhaybhatia

return the max of two heights